# Transformar getElementsByClassName em elementRef

Tags: angular, classes

Fiz um codigo e gostaria de transformar meu getElementsByClassName e elementRef, abaixo mostro como fiz e como tentei ajustar

```
tabContent = this.tabContent.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    for (i = 0; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
      tabContent[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks');
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(' active', '');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para você pegar qualquer elemento **Html** na sintaxe nativa do **`JavaScript`** e transformar para **`Angular`** você pode utilizar o `decorator` **[@ViewChild()](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)** e a tipagem da variável como sendo do tipo [**ElementRef**](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) o que lhe possibilita ter acesso a todas as propriedades daquele elemento através do atributo **nativeElement**:

No seu caso aí a variável **tabContent** já é um @ViewChild() então **tablinks** seguiria a mesma lógica:

```
// Faz os imports
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

// decalara a variável e o tipo como ElementRef
@ViewChild('tablinks', {static, false}) tablinks: ElementRef;

tabContent = this.tabContent.nativeElement.innerHTML;
for (i = 0; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
  tabContent[i].style.display = 'none';
}
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
  tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(' active', '');
}
```

Dependendo da versão do Angular que estiver utilizando *(acho que do 7 para cima)* é necessário declarar um objeto declarando se a instância da variável é estática ou não: `{static, true}`

Comment: Pq do voto negativo? Não entendi!